# Colisão dispara GameOver no Unity

Tags: unity3d

Estou a desenvolver um jogo no Unity que consiste na construção de um predio feito por blocos, e o meu jogo tem um bloco inicial e o resto dos blocos são todos iguais e eles são gerados através de código quando o jogo faz uma certa coisa, no meu script do Game Over eu tenho os blocos com a Tag "bloco" e o que preciso de fazer é  quando um desses blocos cair no chão o jogo acaba, mas isso nao ta a acontecer alguem sabe como resolver ? 
Código do Script "GameOver" :

```
public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour
    {
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject bloco;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "bloco")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O seu script está associado a que objecto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer de duas maneira, verificar se o bloco colidiu com o chão ou verificar se o chão colidiu com o bloco.

Crie um script com o nome `DetetaColisao` e associe ao prefab do bloco, depois crie um plane e dê o nome de `chao`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DetetaColisao : MonoBehaviour
{
    // funcao para verificar todas colisoes do bloco
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        // o bloco colidiu com um gameobject que tem o nome "chao"
        if(col.gameObject.name == "chao")
        {
            // carrega a cena do gameover
            SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
        }
    }
}
```

O seu script para funcionar deveria estar associado ao "chao" neste caso.

Não tenho Unity para testar por isso o código pode estar sujeito a erros.

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!! Problema resolvido !!

Comment: Muito bem :) Considere marcar a pergunta como resolvida. Não gosto de ser rude mas futuramente evite comentários como agradecimento e já agora aproveite para visitar a [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do StackOverflow caso não o tenha feito. Seja bem-vindo ao SO. \o/